# Pass a regexp to an engine to produce highlighting in the pdf output

Tags: highlighting

Is there a way to pass a regexp to an engine (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`... I don't know what could be the right choice) to produce a highlighting of the matches in the pdf output? I need the `.tex` file not be modified.

Let me explain. If I have the file:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

The words foo and bar should be higlighted in the pdf output of this
document, but I need this file not being modified.

An example for a more complex string, e.g. ``highlight this string'',
would be helpfull.

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have something like (this is a conceptual example):

```bash
pdflatex --highlight "\(foo\|bar\)" file.tex
```

and have:

[image]

Please note that I'm familiar with emacs regexp only so, please, specify what kind of regexp you are using.

Another usefull thing should be if I could store the regexps in a file to be passed to the engine.

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I'm not able to use LuaLaTeX but I can try to use it for this particular task if I don't have to file the original `.tex` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua provides various pattern-matching capabilities. It's not "full" regexp, but it's quite similar. LuaTeX lets you assign functions to the `process_input_buffer` callback, where they can act as preprocessors, "on the fly", on the input stream, *before* TeX commences its usual processing.

I suggest you create a separate tex file called, say, `highlight.tex`, as follows:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\textcolor' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
\luaexec{
function colorize ( u )
   return ( "\\textcolor{red}{" .. u .. "}" )
end
function highlight ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "foo" , colorize )
   s = s:gsub ( 'bar' , colorize )
   s = s:gsub ( "``highlight this string''" , colorize )
   return s
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , highlight , "highlight" ) 
}}
```

Then the only modification you'd have to apply to the "main" tex file is to insert the instruction `\input highlight` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input highlight  % <-- new

\begin{document}
The words foo and bar should be highlighted in the pdf output of this
document, but I need this file not being modified.

An example for a more complex string, e.g., ``highlight this string'',
would be helpful.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, but is there a way to store thie code in a file and pass it to LuaLaTex. I mean something like `lualatex "\AtBeginDocument{\input\string./hihglights.txt}" file.tex`?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - Just so I understand: Are you not allowed to insert the instruction `\input highlight` in the preamble of the document you're supposed to be working on?

Comment: Yes, I'm not allowed to write the document for this task.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - Do you want me to delete this answer as it doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Oh, no! Please! It could be a good start point! Also I could start from here to learn useful stuff!

Comment: I succeded to pass the strings to the engine using `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndPreamble`. The only issue I have is with the commands `\pdfoutput=1` and `\pdfminorversion=5`. Any idea to "sterilize" them?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - I'm afraid I seem to be missing some context. How or where do `\pdfoutput=1` and `\pdfminorversion=5` come into the picture?

Comment: You're right. in the real case, not the MWE I have those strings in the documents. I think I should open another question for this. Thank you.