# Redefine \pdfouput=1 to be ignored

Tags: macros, pdftex, luatex, primitives

How I can redefine the command `\pdfoutput=1` to be ignored?

I need to compile a file with `lualatex` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586129/33634) but it contains the command `\pdfoutput=1`. I cannot make changes to the file so I thought I can redefine it at some point. Maybe with `\AtBeginDocument` or with `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndPreamble` passing it to the engine.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: \newcount\pdfoutput somewhere before the command should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a counter variable (primitive, but still), so

```latex
\newcount\pdfoutput
```

should do.  That's not a great idea though, because some code may use that to check if pdfTeX is being used and the test will give a false positive.

Comment: tests relying on it are bound to break anyway, e.g. if luatex85 is loaded, so imho one doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Curiously there are lots of `\ifx\pdfoutput\@undefined` and such in my installation (surely, most are likely fine, but there are a few that can be problematic).  Probably the value of `\pdfoutput` (in an engine that doesn't have it) is more important than it existing or not... Anyway, just rambling :)

Comment: It works. Thanks. Works also with `\pdfminorversion`.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Yes, all are count registers (you can do `\<register>=<number>`) so will work in the same way.  If you have some dimension register, for example `\pdfpagewidth`, you can use `\newdimen` instead

Answer (score 3):

If you compile from the command line,

```bash
lualatex "\let\pdfoutput\outputmode\input filename"
```

will do.